# Is it possible to include custom css in htmlwidgets for R and/or LeafletR?

Tags: r, leaflet, htmlwidgets

I'd like to make some style changes to my leaflet map.

Is it possible to include

- style elements OR
- a custom path to a css file

either via htmlwidgets for R or LeafletR?

Best

Comment: do you have just a little bit of reproducible code or an example of custom leaflet styling?  I think I have an answer, but I do not know.  `htmltools` will definitely be your friend here, but there are some other options we can explore using dependencies.

Comment: also are you using in `rmarkdown` or not?

Comment: no, I don't use rmarkdown. I'd like to use it on a standalone website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With no code whatsoever in your question, answering is very difficult.  I'll attempt an answer.  There are two methods of adding custom `CSS` to an `htmlwidget`.  I will caution up front though that you will **need to be very specific** or use the `!important` override, since there is already quite a [bit of `CSS`](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/leaflet.yaml) that is automatically added to `leaflet`.

**Easy but Less Robust**

`htmlwidgets` can be combined with `tags` from the `htmltools` package.

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

# example from ?leaflet
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()

# there are two approaches to the custom css problem
#  1.  the easy but less robust way
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      # you'll need to be very specific
      tags$style("p{font-size:200%;}")
      # could also use url
      #tags$link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",rel="stylesheet")
    ),
    m
  ))
)
```

**More Robust with htmlDependency**

You can also use the `htmlDependency` which will handle conflicts caused by duplicates.

```
#  2.  you can add dependencies to your leaflet map
#  this mechanism will smartly handle duplicates
#  but carries a little more overhead
str(m$dependencies)  # should be null to start
# 
m$dependencies <- list(
  htmlDependency(
    name = "font-awesome"
    ,version = "4.3.0"
    # if local file use file instead of href below
    #  with an absolute path
    ,src = c(href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css")
    ,stylesheet = "font-awesome.min.css"
  )
)

m
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I followed timelyportfolio browsable() method, but you will have a small window of the map. To fix this you must add: 100vw and 100vh to leaflet and remove margins from the body.

For example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

# example from ?leaflet
m = leaflet(height = '100vh', width = '100vw') %>% addTiles()

# there are two approaches to the custom css problem
#  1.  the easy but less robust way
browsable(
  tagList(list(
    tags$head(
      # you'll need to be very specific
      tags$style("p{font-size:200%;} body{margin: 0px;}")
      # could also use url
      #tags$link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",rel="stylesheet")
    ),
    m
  ))
)
```