# Is there an option to colour text in the layer options box?

Tags: r, leaflet

I need to change the colour of the text in the layer control box.

I know it's possible in Javascript but I need to do it in R. I think it may be something to do with the `layersControlOptions` function, but I cant find any documentation which shows all of the arguments for this.

```
addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
    overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
)
```

Comment: You can add css styling in shiny. How are you displaying the map - using shiny or other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shiny you can do as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('map'),

    # Add custom CSS & Javascript;
    tags$style(".leaflet-control-layers-expanded{color: red}")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(quakes) %>% 
          addTiles() %>% 
          addMarkers() %>% 
          addLayersControl(
              baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
              overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
              options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
          )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The key line being `tags$style(".leaflet-control-layers-expanded{color: red}")`. Edit red as required using a Colour Name, Hex Colour Code, or RGB Colour Code.

**Update**

To display within the RStudio Viewer pane (i.e. without shiny) you can do the following:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

m <- leaflet(quakes) %>% 
     addTiles() %>% 
     addMarkers() %>% 
     addLayersControl(
         baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
         overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
         options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
     )

browsable(
    tagList(
        tags$style(".leaflet-control-layers-expanded{color: red}"),        
        m
    )
)
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720698/is-it-possible-to-include-custom-css-in-htmlwidgets-for-r-and-or-leafletr).

**Further Update**

Based on the need for different colours:

As an aside `form.leaflet-control-layers-list` is an alternative for `.leaflet-control-layers-expanded`

Within that there is a split between `.leaflet-control-layers-base` and `.leaflet-control-layers-overlays` as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('map'),

    # Add custom CSS & Javascript;
    tags$style(".leaflet-control-layers-base{color: red}",
               ".leaflet-control-layers-overlays{color: blue}")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(quakes) %>% 
          addTiles() %>% 
          addMarkers() %>% 
          addLayersControl(
              baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
              overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
              options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
          )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not found how to colour by specific lines as the css does not seem to differentiate.

Comment: Would this allow you to add different colours for different lines in the box, or in this example would the whole thing have to be in red?

Comment: This example would make all text red. I can look into different colours if you'd like?
Inspect element allows you to see the css.

Comment: Different colours would be excellent if thats possible, thanks, this solution has got me most of the way there!